# How to use Awk to format numbers with a thousands separator

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

Can anyone tell me how to use the awk command for this statement "the number will contain commas after every three digits.  For example, 100000000 will become 100,000,000."

I know how to use sed command to obtain this output but I don't know how to use awk, I'm beginner please tell me I'm searching from morning but I didn't get a suitable answer for this so please suggest me best tutorials for learning.

sed command to get the above output:

```
echo "100000000" | sed -E 's/([0-9]{3})/,\1/2g'
```

Comment: What search term are you using? Try "thousands separator". FYI GNU awk has a [printf format modifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html)

Comment: Your `sed` command doesn't do what you think. It only works with 9-digit numbers...

Comment: search term stands for "to search on internet to resolve this"

Comment: Alright! i have seen it'll work just for 9 digit numbers and i want a same output for same numbers but by using the awk can you help me?

Comment: Cannot display fractions properly. For example 11.23 becomes 11,.23. It is better to use printf with suitable formatting.

Answer (score 22):

## A locale-independent solution with manual formatting

This should work on any POSIX-compatible OS regardless of the locales installed.

```
$ printf "1\n10\n100\n1000\n10000\n100000\n1000000\n10000000\n100000000\n" \
| awk '{ len=length($0); res=""; for (i=0;i<=len;i++) { res=substr($0,len-i+1,1) res; if (i > 0 && i < len && i % 3 == 0) { res = "," res } }; print res }'
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
100,000
1,000,000
10,000,000
100,000,000
```

## A solution that uses `printf` and the en_US locale.

The `printf` sequence `%'d` prints a decimal integer formatted with the current locale's thousands separator.

```
$ printf "1\n10\n100\n1000\n10000\n100000\n1000000\n10000000\n100000000\n" \
| LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 awk '{ printf("%'"'"'d\n", $0) }'
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
100,000
1,000,000
10,000,000
100,000,000
```

Comment: This second half of the answer could be improved by making it more clear that "printf" is both a shell command and an awk function. Additionally, if one is using awk _only_ to format numbers, then a more elegant solution is the printf command instead of this answer's AWKward single-double-single-double-single quote syntax. `LC_ALL=en_US printf "%'d\n" 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000 10000000 100000000`

Comment: I suggest using `awk -v fmt="%'d\n"` and use `printf(fmt, $0)`. The current quoting of `printf("%'"'"'d\n", $0)` is  a bit much. ☺

Answer (score 5):

```
gawk 'END {
        printf("%-20s %\47 10i \n",  "Number of records: ", NR)
        printf("%-20s %\47 10.2f \n",  "Number of records: ", NR)
    }' /var/log/kern.log

Number of records:        2,818
Number of records:     2,818.00 `
```

Comment: Upvoted as I'll be using that octal trick (`%\47 10i`). You may want to improve the answer by explaining it a little, though, instead of just showing the code. AWK can be a bit cryptic, especially for someone learning it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is [`numfmt`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/numfmt.1.html) (which is part of `coreutils` and is included in Debian by default)

```
$ printf "1\n10\n100\n1000\n10000\n100000\n1000000\n10000000\n100000000\n" \
| LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 numfmt --padding=12 --grouping
           1
          10
         100
       1,000
      10,000
     100,000
   1,000,000
  10,000,000
 100,000,000
$ printf "1\n10\n100\n1000\n10000\n100000\n1000000\n10000000\n100000000\n" \
| LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 numfmt --grouping
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
100,000
1,000,000
10,000,000
100,000,000
```

You can also format the values directly with `%'f` instead of using `--grouping`

```
$ printf "1\n10\n100\n1000\n10000\n100000\n1000000\n10000000\n100000000\n" \
| LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 numfmt --format "%'f"
$ printf "1\n10\n100\n1000\n10000\n100000\n1000000\n10000000\n100000000\n" \
| LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 numfmt --format "%'12f"
```

Comment: Numfmt is powerful and I use it, but maybe this answer should add a caveat. At least as of 2024, it is extremely brittle, has poor defaults, and its field separator cannot be a regular expression (unlike AWK's `FS`). To work around these issues I find myself having to add needlessly verbose argument, `--invalid=ignore ---field=-`, nearly every time I use numfmt.  Here's a concrete example using trivial input from sysfs, `cd .  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/; grep . * | numfmt --invalid=ignore ---field=- d: --format="%'12f"` .