# printf, awk ... How to format a number with space to the thousands

Tags: shell, awk, sed, printf, bc

Is there a simple way to separate a very large number per thousands with printf, awk, sed ?

So 10000000000000 become 10 000 000 000 000

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to format a string with just an integer number or is this a text file with many numbers or ...?

Comment: You're not satisfied with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249116/how-to-use-awk-to-format-numbers-with-a-thousands-separator  ?

Comment: @Philippos, any number (floats or intergers) are to format

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, no this is not exhaustive.

Comment: If you want a float like `12345.6789` formatted as `12 345.678 9`, the story gets more complicated ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple combination of sed and rev could be employed -

```
echo  "I have 10000013984 oranges" | rev | sed "s/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/& /g" | rev
```

first rev is required to replace number from right to left , and the second one for bringing back the original string.

Comment: That inserts a space before `999` in `I have 999 oranges` though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thanks, i have found another solution without rev
`echo 10000013984.23 |  sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/ &/;ta'`
this could be enough with floats with maximum 3 decimals after the decimal point

Comment: Why only 3 votes on this accepted answer, while 12 votes on the other answer?

Answer (score 12):

With some `printf` implementations (including GNU `printf` and the `printf` builtin of `ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash` and `lksh` (but not `dash` nor `yash`) on GNU systems) and assuming your system has a French (of France or Canada at least), or Swedish or Slovenian or Macedonian or Kyrgyz locale (and a few more, that is, those that have space as the thousand separator):

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR locale -k thousands_sep
thousands_sep=" "
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR printf "%'d\n" 10000000000
10 000 000 000
```

Also works with some `awk` implementations:

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR awk 'BEGIN{printf "%'\''d\n", 1e10}'
10 000 000 000
```

You can use `LC_NUMERIC` instead of `LC_ALL` if you know `LC_ALL` is otherwise not set.

Comment: how did you get rid of the dots or comma's ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, the thousand separator is _space_ in French (also in Slovenian and Swedish). See the output of `LC_ALL=fr_FR locale -k thousands_sep`

Comment: Indeed it is, I only had fr_BE to test with, sorry!

Comment: that's the case when the Frenchman knows what he's talking about )

Answer (score 5):

You need to loop with `sed`:

```
echo "9765625000 * 1024 = 10000000000000" | sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1 \2/;ta'
9 765 625 000 * 1 024 = 10 000 000 000 000
```

*(Thank you for the improvement, Stéphane!)*

Or better readable, but maybe not compatible with older `sed` versions, with extended regular expressions:

```
echo "9765625000 * 1024 = 10000000000000" | sed -E -e :a -e 's/(.*[0-9])([0-9]{3})/\1 \2/;ta'
9 765 625 000 * 1 024 = 10 000 000 000 000
```

Comment: Or POSIXly `sed -e :1 -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1 \2/;t1'`

Comment: Although it's just a matter of time to include `-E` for ERE into the standard, I have to admit that your solution to take advantage of the greedy `.*` is far more elegant than my clumpy `([^0-9]|$)`!

Comment: More simple: `sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/ &/;ta'`

Comment: @rcspam Correct, but only for GNU `sed`. `\B` expands POSIX, `:a;` violates POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with the thousands separator defined by the current locale, you can use the `perl` [Number::Format](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Format) module like this:

```
$ perl -e 'use Number::Format qw(format_number);
           print format_number(shift),"\n"' 10000000000000
10,000,000,000,000
```

(extra linefeeds added for readability.  this can be entered all on one line)

If you want spaces separating the thousands regardless of locale:

```
perl -e 'use Number::Format;
         my $num= new Number::Format(-thousands_sep=>" ");
         print $num->format_number(shift), "\n"' 10000000000000
10 000 000 000 000
```

Answer (score 1):

with `LANG=nl_BE`

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  I=0
  T=1
  while ( I < 10 ) {
    S = sprintf("%'\''d",T)
    gsub(/\./," ",S)
    print S
    T *= 10
    I++
  }
}'
```

gives

```
1
10
100
1 000
10 000
100 000
1 000 000
10 000 000
100 000 000
1 000 000 000
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all,

I have found a solution that suits me with sed.
It works with integers and floats (with less than 3 decimals).

```
echo 12120013984.235 |  sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/ &/;ta'
```

I have found it here: http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/cmdline/sed-insert-commas.html with the explanations:

***\B***
  Matches anything that is not a word boundary.

***[0-9]***
  Matches any digit.

***\{3\}***
  Matches three repetitions of whatever precedes it (in this case, a digit).

**\>**
  Matches a word boundary at the end of a word.

Comment: That's GNU-specific though (contrary to @Philippos' similar one).